# Magento 2 custom API giving "Class string does not exist" error

Tags: magento2, rest-api, api

In Magento 2.4, I am using custom API and it is giving the below error.

```
{
"message": "Class string does not exist",
"code": -1
}
```

I have tried [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/251601/35778) and [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/358702/35778) solution. But nothing worked. Any solution for this?

Comment: Can you share code?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. In my case, It is due to the return type of the response specified in the Interface file(Usually at Api/Interface.php).

Sample code:

here it is: ***@return \Vendor\Module\Api\Data\ResponseDataInterface***

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Api;
interface SampleInterface
{
/**
 * GET for Post api
 * @param string $customerId
 * @return \Vendor\Module\Api\Data\ResponseDataInterface
 */

public function getDetails($customerId);
```

}